# Oracle Transportable Database export ORA-39340: unsupported object, INDEX

Tags: oracle, expdp

I want to get data dump from PDB(Transportable Database). DB version 12.2.0.1.0. Enterprise Edition.
Before I get export I applied oracle 27162931 and 27162975 opatch. Then I altered tablespaces except sysaux and system, temp and undotbs1:

```
alter tablespace users read only;
```

[image]

Next I logged in to the database using sysdba and then created directory and granted read, write access:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY exp_dir AS 'D:\export_db';

GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY exp_dir TO system;
```

Then I logged from system and ran export command like below,

```
expdp system/XXXXXX@D1943 dumpfile=DB12cdmp.dmp directory=exp_dir transportable=always full=y version=12.2.0.1.0 logfile=exp_test1.log
```

But I'm getting error like below,
Processing object type

> DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/DOMAIN_INDEX/SECONDARY_TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
>
> ORA-39340: unsupported object, INDEX:"ABC"."SYS_IL0000903003C00006$$"
>   will be skipped. ORA-39340: unsupported object,
>   INDEX:"ABC"."SYS_IL0000903008C00002$$" will be skipped.

Comment: for now there is no real fix for it, as a workaround, you need to re-create unsupported object on the target database manually

Answer (score 0):

[ORA-39043 Or ORA-39340 May Be Raised During Full Transportable Export of the Database (Doc ID 2365679.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2365679.1)

> This issue is currently investigated in bug 27244546.
>
> When encountering this problem, recreate the text index after
>   importing into the new database.